# HTML/CSS Align Images in a grid with hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

I made a grid of images and through the CSS I aligned them all centered, close to each other in the grid.
As soon as I go to add the hover to zoom by hovering the mouse over, the images are no longer aligned, but one below the other.
The HTML code is like this:

```css
.section-wrap img:hover {
      width: 120px; 
      height: 120px;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .section-wrap img {
      display: block;
      border: 0; 
    }

    .section-wrap {
      padding: 120px 0;
      position: relative;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
```

```html
<section class="section-wrap bg-dark-overlay" style="background-image: url(img/background_abstract_test.png);">
  <div class="container" id="brands">
    <div class="title-row text-center">
      <p class="subtitle">Unsere Top Marken</p>
      <br>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
    </div> <!-- end slider -->
  </div>
</section>
```

I also tried to write the hover effect in a new class and recall it separately, but nothing.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your images to `display: block`, which will force them to be visible one below the other. The following works better, but the alignment when one of them is resized is not the prettiest:

```css
.section-wrap img:hover {
      width: 120px; 
      height: 120px;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .section-wrap img {
      /* changed this: display: block; to: */
      display: inline-block;
      border: 0; 
    }

    .section-wrap {
      padding: 120px 0;
      position: relative;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
```

```html
<section class="section-wrap bg-dark-overlay" style="background-image: url(img/background_abstract_test.png);">
  <div class="container" id="brands">
    <div class="title-row text-center">
      <p class="subtitle">Unsere Top Marken</p>
      <br>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"></a>
    </div> <!-- end slider -->
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the hover effect can't override the inline width - height properties.
Moving default styles to css file might be fix this.

```css
.section-wrap img {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

.section-wrap img:hover {
  width: 120px; 
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0;
}

.section-wrap img {
  display: block;
  border: 0; 
}

.section-wrap {
  padding: 120px 0;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-wrap bg-dark-overlay">
    <div class="container" id="brands">
        <div class="title-row text-center">
            <p class="subtitle">Unsere Top Marken</p>
            <br>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
            <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="img" /></a>
        </div> <!-- end slider -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you changed the image display to block.
for fixing it you can change the display to inline-block:

```
.section-wrap img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0; 
}
```

for making it even more next to each other you can set the float to left which helps you to set them left to each other. like this:

```
.section-wrap img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 0; 
}
```